# Constructing a box to find its volume

Tags: calculus

12) We want to construct a closed box with a square base. We only have $20m^{2}$ of material to use in construction of the box. Assuming that all the material is used in the construction process, determine the maximum volume that the box can have to the nearest hundredth of a cubic meter.

**answer**

Let the dimensions of the base be $t$ while its height is $h$

Surface area of the box - $2t^{2} + 4th = 20$

Its volume = $t^{2}h$

substituting value of h into the formula for volume and then finding the derivative to find the value of $t$ and $h$, gives the answer as $6.09$ square meters.

Can someone confirm this answer for me

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Solving the surface equation for $h$, plugging the result in the volume equation and computing the local maximum of this function of $t$ does work. The maximal volume comes out to $\left(\sqrt{\frac{10}{3}}\right)^3 \approx 6.0858$ cubic meters as you computed. Did you notice that the optimum is an exact cube?